# Cloudbees Docker Plugin - "?" Folder

Tags: jenkins, docker, cloudbees

I'm using Cloudbees Docker Plugin 1.9 together with Jenkins 2.25 to Build my Project within Docker Containers.

Jenkins itself is also running under Docker 1.12.2 on Ubuntu 14.4.

The JENKINS_HOME directory is mounted as Volume so every job, workspace etc. is available under User "ubuntu" on the Host System.

When running a Job with Cloudbees Docker Plugin it creates a "?" folder in the workspace containing different hidden directories (e.g. .oracle_jre_usage, .m2, .gradle etc.)

Can anybody explain, what part / Plugin of the Jenkins Job creates this folder and why it is named "?"

Comment: Same problem here, did you find any solution?

Comment: Not yet, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered similar issue when mounting a source folder into a Maven container as `WORKDIR` for build.

JRE seems to take `WORKDIR/$(id -un)` as the home directory (`${user.home}` in the settings) and creates those folders.
The '?' probably is a result of failing to resolve the host's UID in the container, which I did with `docker run --rm -u $(id -u):$(id -g) ...`.
I was able to modify `apache-maven/conf/settings.xml` to change the path if `.m2` to persist the cache on another host mount. However due to [this issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8135224) `.oracle_jre_usage` will always be created and log the timestamp.

The solution was probably to not set `WORKDIR` to the workspace, so that `${user.home}` will point to `/?/` which will be removed with the container.